# Store multiple Strings in a single postgresql record using Spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I found this question with different programming languages or different database

Im trying to make a portal to generate multiple choice quizes
the front end will send me a huge json at some point there will be an array of Questions objects
evry object should have:

- the question
- the right answer
- a list of wrong answers ( min 2 max 4 )
- the id of the CourseSpecifics object...

I need to store (if possible) the list of wrong answers ( Strings ) in a single record of my postgresql db

this is my class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Questions {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Column(name ="question",nullable = false)
String question;

@Column(name ="answer",nullable = false)
String answer;

@Column(name ="wrong_answers",nullable = false)
List<String> wrongAnswers;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name ="fk_specifics",nullable = false)
CourseSpecifics fkSpecifics;

}
```

This is the exact point where i have some doubts (lets skip the rest for the moment, i know i can improve it )

```
@Column(name ="wrong_answers",nullable = false)
List<String> wrongAnswers;
```

im also using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` to generate db from spring structure but its not mandatory

My questions are :

What is the best data type to use on spring in this situation for `wrongAnswers` ?
What is the best column definition to use on db according to the data type of `wrongAnswers` ?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely looking for the @ElementCollection annotation. This will allow you to have a list of strings as you have it right now.

However, it use a new table! Which you don't seem to want. Without binding yourself to a single database (by using arrays or something) your best bet may be to write a converter to serialize a list of strings into a single string.

I'd personally revaluate if your single record is a super strong requirement.